extra numbers attached to my values (PHP)
I'm facing a very odd phenomenon when trying to separate the whole numbers and decimals from a float value.
<?php

echo "<br>" . numToWords(1004712896.17);

function numToWords($value) : String
{   
    // $words is used to store the translated string
    $words = "";
    print "<br>VALUE: $value";
    $whole = floor($value);
    print "<br>WHOLE: $whole";    
    $deci = $value - $whole;
    print "<br>DECI: $deci";

    // continue to translate numbers into words
    ...
    return $words;
}

The out put shows the decimal part having some extra numbers attached at the end:
VALUE: 1004712896.17
WHOLE: 1004712896
DECI: 0.16999995708466001004712896

I noticed that the last 12 numbers are the whole-number part of my value. Also, it is not 0.17 as what I entered, but is 0.1699999...
I can get back 17 if I multiply it by 100 and ceil() the result, but still, the extra numbers are present in my result:
$deci = ceil(($value - $whole) * 100);

the output:
DECI: 17001004712896

So... What have I done wrong? I don't think memory corruption is the cause as I tried to close the tab and re-open it, and even closed my browser and re-open it, the problem persists. And memory overflow is not the problem, since nothing changed even after I've reduced the value to the range of thousands.
Is there something I must do before performing any calculation to prevent this, or is this a bug of PHP?
Using XAMPP Version 8.0.30 on FireFox (Latest).
Edit:
trying another method, by using the string equivalent of the value, and then locate the position of the period, and separate the 2 parts into 2 strings, still, the extra numbers are attached to the substring, even when I specifically said I only want 2 characters for my decimal string:
$valstr = strval($value);
print "<br>VALSTR: $valstr";
$pos = strpos($valstr, ".", 0);
$intstr = substr($valstr, 0, $pos);
$decstr = substr($valstr, $pos+1, 2);
print "<br>POS: $pos";
print "<br>IntStr: $intstr";
print "<br>DecStr: $decstr";

output:
VALSTR: 8712896.34
POS: 7
IntStr: 8712896
DecStr: 34008712896 // supposed to be 34 only
I'm starting to think this is a bug in PHP...

looks like issue with floating point you can try to round off to 2 decimal places to get round of value
screenshot

While the other post mentioned that it's IEEE 754 that's screwed up the floating point values, my other questions stands unanswered: What should I do to prevent such problem when working with floating point values? Although I didn't show the rest of my codes, it is indeed making my translation failed later on, as it is not the value I am expecting: How do I get back 17, and exactly 17 for my decimal part.

Must you use floating numbers rather than strings?

"... my other questions stand ..." - This is why a question on StackOverflow should focus on one problem at the time

As I said, I didn't ask about why the floating point operation is screwed, I am asking for HOW DO I AVOID THIS FLOATING POINT OPERATION ERROR, and it is still unanswered, please don't mark it as similar to the other post, THEY ARE DIFFERENT. Thank you.

If the input string is 8712896.34, how could you get DecStr: 34008712896? https://3v4l.org/VQr3S

@shigo - indeed, that's a mystery to me as well, but that's is not my question in the post, I am asking of how can I prevent these extra numbers attached in my results.

This is inevitable, the reason is well explained in that dup question. So usually currency type numbers are stored as integers or strings. The BC library used in the answer below also processes strings rather than floating numbers.

that's a mystery to me as well...did you look at Shingo's demo link, at the end of the comment? The code doesn't produce the value you're claiming - which makes the question a lot more difficult to understand.

well, I think it would be good to use bcdiv() instead of floor().
<?php

echo "<br>" . numToWords(1004712896.17);

function numToWords($value) : String
{   
    // $words is used to store the translated string
    $words = "";
    print "<br>VALUE: $value";

    // Use bc math functions to get whole and decimal parts
    $whole = bcdiv($value, 1, 0);
    print "<br>WHOLE: $whole";    
    
    $fraction = bcsub($value, $whole, 2); 
    print "<br>DECI: $fraction";

    $deci = bcmul($fraction, 100, 0); 
    print "<br>DECI INTEGER: $deci";

    // continue to translate numbers into words
    ...
    return $words;
}

